# Sencha touch 2 ajax call how to set custom headers?

Tags: javascript, ajax, azure, http-headers, sencha-touch-2

I have been struggling with this for the last few days. What I want to do is add custom header called `foo` to the ajax get request and set the value for it.

I have tried this:

```
Ext.Azure.invokeApi({
    url: 'myUrl',
    method:'get',
    headers: {
        "foo": "some data"
    },

    callback: function(options, success, response) {
        console.log(response.responseText);
    }
});
```

But I cannot see my custom header being sent to the server when watching google chromes developer console networking tab. Also I cannot access its value in my server. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You won't like to hear that: but you did it correctly. The headers should have been added to the request. Might be some typo in the actual code?

Comment: What version of Sencha Touch are you using? v2.3.1 works as expected doing what you posted.

Comment: Hmm at least they aren't visible from the google chromes developer console.

Comment: @arthurakay I'm actually passing these headers into azure invoke api call but this should work also?